# dplyr r language - issues using unique() function

Tags: r, dplyr

I had a quick, and probably simple question. I am trying to generate a unique list of subjects, but after I use the unique() function, the list generated comes out as this:

```
1  Subject 1
13 Subject 2
25 Subject 3
37 Subject 4
...
```

I wanted to see if I could get the list in a format of a vector so that I could use it in a for loop with the length as the end of count parameter. If I try to use the data.frame(t(name_of_dataframe) then all of my unique results disappear and are transposed back into a dataframe.
`--> [1] "Subject 1" "Subject 2" ...` [This is what I'm aiming for as a result].

```
  graph.data <- data.frame()
  graph.data <- read.csv(file = filename, header = TRUE)
  subj <- unique(select(graph.data, Subject))
```

Comment: Can't you just subset the column? For example `unique(mydf)[,1]`

Comment: I think I actually just figured out the issue. The unique function created column names, and it was throwing me off, because it printed out the same as the output for position usually would, except the column names where from the position the unique instance was acquired from.